# Is there any function available in MySQL which can group the result of Dates into days wise split up

Tags: mysql, grouping

SQL Table Schema:

```
Id    CaseID   CounterID  ActionID   CurrentStart             CreatedDate 
973   11       13         16         2017-12-11 09:28:11    2017-12-11 09:28:11
```

I need a result like below

```
CounterID  0-30(Range 1)    31-60(Range 2)      61-90 
16         22(Count)        20(Count)           18(Count)
```

and so on

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a solution with a group by here is the simplest one :

```
<!-- language: sql -->
select 
    Id,
    sum(case when CurrentStart - CreatedDate &lt;= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) INF30,
    sum(case when CurrentStart - CreatedDate BETWEEN 31 AND 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) BET3060,
    sum(case when CurrentStart - CreatedDate &gt; 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) SUP60
from tablename where Id is not null group by Id;
```

Here is another form I suggest to help you build such queries :

- In a sub-request, you get the Id, and three columns to know if the date is in range with this CASE : 1 if date is in range, 0 otherwise (the sub-request is named **INNER_TABLE** here)
- You group by Id the results of this sub-request and take the sum of the columns for the ranges.

```
select
        INNER_TABLE.Id,
        sum(INNER_TABLE.INF30) INF30,
        sum(INNER_TABLE.BET3060) BET3060,
        sum(INNER_TABLE.SUP60) SUP60
    from (select
            Id,
               case when CreatedDate - CurrentStart <= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END INF30,
               case when CreatedDate - CurrentStart BETWEEN 31 AND 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END BET3060,
               case when CreatedDate - CurrentStart > 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END SUP60
        from tablename where Id is not null) INNER_TABLE
    group by INNER_TABLE.Id;
```

Otherwise, another simple solution :

- You take the list of different CounterId on which you want to do the group by
  `(select distinct Id from tablename where id is not null) as ids`
- You use a sub-request in each part of the select for your count :
  `(select count(*) from tablename where Id = ids.Id and CurrentStart - CreatedDate < 30)`
- Apply the same for the three selected fields

```
select
    ids.Id,
    (select count(*) from tablename where Id = ids.Id and CurrentStart - CreatedDate <= 30) INF_30,
    (select count(*) from tablename where Id = ids.Id and CurrentStart - CreatedDate > 30 and CurrentStart - CreatedDate <= 60) BET_30_60,
    (select count(*) from tablename where Id= ids.Id and CurrentStart - CreatedDate > 60) SUP_60
from (select distinct Id from tablename where Id is not null) ids;
```

Where `tablename` is the name of your table of course :)